# Any ideas how to implement ComboBox to represent hierarchical data?

Tags: wpf, combobox

Does anybody saw control like this somewhere?
I need to make such control to represent hierarchical data (it should be generic very likely, i.e. data binding, templates support).
Something like combination of ComboBox and MenuItem’s.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I made it by custom control inherited from ComboBox, custom ComboBoxItem inherited from  HeaderedItemsControl and using HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will redefine the combobox itemtemplate with some [hierarchicaldatatemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) along with [popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Just put ComboBoxes on a form and bind the ItemsSource to the top level collection.

Then bind the DataContext of the next ComboBox to the SelectedItem of the box on the left and bind its ItemSource to the collection of items.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to bind to SelectedItem?

E.G.

Column1 
   Public String Name 
   Public List Column2s

So you bind the first combox to List with he displaymemberpath = name

Then on the second combobox you bind to Column1 selecteditem with items source path of Column2s

The trick is to build up the Lists within the Lists within the Lists