# WPF MVVM - Binding highlighted item in Combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to bind a highlighted ComboBox item in WPF/MVVM?

The reason I want this behavior is that I want to be able to right-click on a ComboBox item and pass the argument (Item Id for that matter) in the CommandParameter.

Since no item is actually selected until I left-click on the item, I have no args to pass...

Thoughts please?

```
<ComboBox.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Delete Expense Category" Command="{Binding DeleteMenuItemCommand}"
CommandTarget="{Binding HighlightedExpenseCategory}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
</ComboBox.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: If you want to right-click the ComboBoxItem, why not put the ContextMenu in the ComboBoxItem instead of the ComboBox?

Comment: valid point, but I dont have ComboBoxItems since that's binded from ItemSource. Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Then put that as part of the ComboBox's `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Could you please write a code snippet? I started scrambling something but got stuck as WPF is fairly new to me...

Answer (score 2):

First a question: what is your ultimate goal and can you approach it without having the user right click on a context menu item? Perhaps what you may want is a hierarchical combobox like in the image here [Any ideas how to implement ComboBox to represent hierarchical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797336/any-ideas-how-to-implement-combobox-to-represent-hierarchical-data) . Though that may not suit you if you indeed just want to perform an action on an item in your combo box.

With that aside, then HighCore put you on the right track (sorry HighCore, I'm going to steal a little of your thunder here, but as a consolation I'm giving you a couple votes). The key thing is that the ContextMenu is a property of the ComboBoxItem and not the ComboBox itself.

This code snippet may help you get a step closer, though I haven't tested beyond XamlPad. You'll likely have an additional step of making sure your bindings can reach your view model with the command as well as your menu item's Id property, wherever you've defined that. Try the Binding's RelativeSource, but come back if you need help with that. Good luck!

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBox.Resources>
          <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
             <MenuItem Header="Delete Expense Category" Command="{Binding DeleteMenuItemCommand}"
              CommandTarget="{Binding HighlightedExpenseCategory}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
          </ContextMenu>
   </ComboBox.Resources>

   <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
         <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
         </Style.Setters>
      </Style>
   </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="1" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet... your first question made me thinking may be i shouldn't go with the "right-click" way, as the application has 3 editable comboboxes and it might be user-frustrating if he had to right click in three different places. i think to concentrate the data from those comboboxes in "preferences" window will make more sense UI-wise. as per my original question i kept digging and seems like the mvvm light toolbox has solutions to offer.